# Closed Source Java Applications

Tags: java

I am taking programming courses and we have been discussing Open Source and having a bit of an argument over the confusion.  Just because Java is Open Source, the licensing on developed applications starts at the developer, correct?  Someone is arguing about the use of code from a complete program just because "Java is Open Source".  If I write a Java application, what are the limitations on how I can distribute it or how someone else can use it?  Assume here that I DO NOT want someone having access to my source.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenJDK uses the [GPLv2 with classpath exception](http://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html).

If you modify the JDK itself and distribute binary versions, you must provide its modified source and distribute it under the same terms, but this does not apply to Java applications you write yourself. You are free to distribute them under whatever terms you wish.

I am not a lawyer, though. You might want to check with one.

See also http://www.sun.com/software/opensource/java/faq.jsp#g

Comment: In otherwords, if your program just links to the Java libraries you can use whatever license you want. You aren't forced to use the GPL and give away your source code.

Comment: Yes, you are limited only if you link to parts of the JDK itself which are not covered by the classpath exception. But at that point you're writing applications in C, not Java.

Comment: If you work in a big enough company, someone somewhere in the business will have a panic every six months or so and need this explaining to them after they put out a memo banning the use of Java.

Answer (score 3):

No, the programming language itself is completely unrelated to the licensing of the programs.
A normal Java program does not bundle with the standard runtime, only the compiled class files, which are written by the programmer(s).
You don't need to credit Microsoft Word if you published a .doc Word document.

Comment: *"the programming language itself is completely unrelated to the licensing of the programs"*.  As a general statement, that is false.  A programming language implementation's license terms **could** require you to open source an software.  It so happens that OpenJDK does not, do this nor does any other major programming language implementation.  (And Microsoft **could have** written their license terms such that you had to credit them in every MSWord document.)

Answer (score 0):

When you write a Java application, you're free to license your application however you want.  You don't need to distribute your source code.  Sun's open source license is for the JDK itself, not Java applications you write in the Java language.

See the [FAQ](http://www.sun.com/software/opensource/java/faq.jsp#g) on this, particularly the licensing and classpath exception information.

Comment: That is what I thought and was arguing.  Sun's OS license is so that we as developers can use Java freely to create our own programs that we can license and distribute however we wish.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the correct license, you may want to obfuscate your code at compile time, before shipping the product. Otherwise it will be (at least to a large extent) accessible with the help of a decompiler. This doesn't make it "open source" of course, but it will be easy to copy.

Comment: Unfortunately this particular instance is regarding the "borrowing" of source code prior to distribution.

Answer (score 0):

People have closed source Java programs all the time. The issue though is protecting your code.

To stop most people (and make others bored and move on) do what Lauri said and obscure your code. Don't just use class file obscurification, use source code obscurification. There are a few programs out there that will do it. Do note though that if someone cared and had time, its impossible to prevent someone from reverse engineering Java code.

Answer (score 0):

@Lord.Quackstar

Thanks.  I understand obfuscation and would use it if or when I want to distribute closed source code.  As I mentioned in another response, this inquiry was more about someone arguing about being able to use someone else's code because "Java is open source" even though that particular code is unreleased and not intended for open source use.